# Two different issuers of a X.509 certificate

Tags: certificate, openssl

The URL https://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/ds/ is protected by TLS. Mozilla Firefox reports that its certificate is issued by

```
CN = TERENA SSL CA 2
O = TERENA
L = Amsterdam
ST = Noord-Holland
C = NL
```

The command "openssl" reports

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.info.ucl.ac.be:443
(skipped)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=--/ST=SomeState/L=SomeCity/O=SomeOrganization/OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit/CN=testwww2.info.ucl.ac.be/emailAddress=root@testwww2.info.ucl.ac.be
   i:/C=--/ST=SomeState/L=SomeCity/O=SomeOrganization/OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit/CN=testwww2.info.ucl.ac.be/emailAddress=root@testwww2.info.ucl.ac.be
---
```

Different issuers. How is this even possible?

Comment: It appears to be an old Site for an undergrad computer science lectures and tests dating back to 2003. Perhaps the chain of trust between root cert (c) authority and issuer (i) is expired.  Try a different browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s simple, really: [SNI – Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). It’s an extension that allows the client to pass the server name along to the TLS handshake. This, combined with [name-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) (multiple domains on a single IP address) allows the server to present different certificates for different host names. OpenSSL’s s_client by default does not include a host name in the handshake.

The following command yields the expected result:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.info.ucl.ac.be:443 -servername www.info.ucl.ac.be
```

This server apparently hosts multiple websites, one of which ([the default website](https://130.104.230.28)) is used only for internal testing, where self-signed certificates are normal.